# Running Jupyter Notebook environment without creating a new file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

Is it possible to run the Jupyter Notebook environment without creating a new .ipynb file? I often find myself in need of quick data inspection and feel like creating a new notebook would not be necessary but the perks of the notebook environment would be very appreciated because some operations might turn out to be quite bothersome using only the Python terminal interpreter.